# Disable DEBUG logs in gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm running [gstreamer in docker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/examples-gstreamer-plugin.html) and `GST_DEBUG` can be used to turn on additional debugging logs, but even if I set `GST_DEBUG=2` or `GST_DEBUG=3`, then several `DEBUG` logs still happen. Here's an example:

```
2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - postReadCallback(): Wrote 65524 bytes to Kinesis Video. Upload stream handle: 0
2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - postReadCallback(): Wrote 65524 bytes to Kinesis Video. Upload stream handle: 0
2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - postReadCallback(): Wrote 65524 bytes to Kinesis Video. Upload stream handle: 0
2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - postReadCallback(): Wrote 31003 bytes to Kinesis Video. Upload stream handle: 0
2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - postReadCallback(): Pausing CURL read for upload handle: 0
2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - postWriteCallback(): Curl post body write function for stream with handle: DaveTest and upload handle: 0 returned: {"EventType":"RECEIVED","FragmentTimecode":1633701893567,"FragmentNumber":"91343852333181580945486776886085710683522911738"}

2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - fragmentAckReceivedHandler invoked
2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - postReadCallback(): Wrote 20153 bytes to Kinesis Video. Upload stream handle: 0
2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - postReadCallback(): Pausing CURL read for upload handle: 0
2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - postWriteCallback(): Curl post body write function for stream with handle: DaveTest and upload handle: 0 returned: {"EventType":"BUFFERING","FragmentTimecode":1633701895543,"FragmentNumber":"91343852333181580950438537043227232143278319293"}

2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - fragmentAckReceivedHandler invoked
2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - postWriteCallback(): Curl post body write function for stream with handle: DaveTest and upload handle: 0 returned: {"EventType":"PERSISTED","FragmentTimecode":1633701893567,"FragmentNumber":"91343852333181580945486776886085710683522911738"}

2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - fragmentAckReceivedHandler invoked
2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - postReadCallback(): Wrote 9598 bytes to Kinesis Video. Upload stream handle: 0
2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - postReadCallback(): Pausing CURL read for upload handle: 0
2021-10-08 14:04:55 [139759980640000] DEBUG - Kinesis Video client and stream metrics
    >> Overall storage byte size: 536870912
    >> Available storage byte size: 536261448
    >> Allocated storage byte size: 609464
    >> Total view allocation byte size: 144080
    >> Total streams frame rate (fps): 1175
    >> Total streams transfer rate (bps): 29187312 (28503 Kbps)
    >> Current view duration (ms): 433
    >> Overall view duration (ms): 1999
    >> Current view byte size: 283686
    >> Overall view byte size: 606536
    >> Current frame rate (fps): 1175.58
    >> Current transfer rate (bps): 29187312 (28503 Kbps)
```

How can I turn these off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the `kvssink` plugin and that it has it's own logging setup. It can be set using a config file and `log-config` with the path to that file ([see here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/issues/773#issuecomment-951056014))

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you set this variable? I was using it multiple times by exporting it: `export GST_DEBUG=3` and it worked as it should. See this link: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstinfo.html?gi-language=c for info how to use it programatically.

Comment: Yes, I'm setting that and it works for `gstreamer` but the issue was the `kvssink` plugin and I posted an answer on how to address that